# PHP foreach imprime solo una fila

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando llenar una tabla desde mysql con php, al momento de querer obtener los registros con fetchall() solo me devuelve el registro con id: 1, probé cambiando el id a 1 a otros registros eliminando el registro anterior con id: 1 y solo obtengo ese registro. Hice un vardump para ver el array que devuelve la consulta y me devuelve el primer registro que hay en la tabla. El archivo de la conexión:

```
<?php 

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$dbName='dinschema';
$user ='root';
$pass='';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';
$enlace = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try{
    $pdo= new PDO($enlace,$user,$pass,$options);
foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * from personas') as $fila) {
        print_r($fila);
    }   //Ciclo que imprime todos los registros

}catch (PDOException $e){
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    die();
}
?>
```

Este es el código que utilizo para hacer el fetch:

```
    <?php
include_once 'conexion.php';
echo ' el index';
$sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM personas p, direccion d WHERE p.idPersonas = d.idDireccion';
$gsent=$pdo -> prepare($sql_leer);
$gsent->execute();
$resultado = $gsent->fetchAll();
var_dump($resultado);
?>
```

Esta es la tabla:

```
  <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter-bootstrap  mw-100 ml-0 ml-xl-5">
                        <colgroup class="table-sorter-colgroup">
                            <col>  <col>
                            <col>  <col>
                            <col>  <col>                               
                            <col>  <col>                               
                            <col>  <col>
                            <col>  <col>                                
                            <col>  <col>                                                       
                        </colgroup>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                               
                            <th>Folio</th>
                            <th>Foto</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Fecha de captura</th>
                            <th>Carrera</th>
                            <th>Escolaridad</th>
                            <th>Teléfono</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Selecciona un género">Género</th>
                            <th>RFC</th>
                            <th>CURP</th>
                            <th>Dirección</th>
                            <th>Observaciones</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="bodyTabla">
                        <?php if(!empty($resultado)):?>
                            <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato):?>                               
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['idPersonas'] ?></td>                                     
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['foto'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['nombre']." " .$dato['apellidoP']." " .$dato['apellidoM'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['fechaCaptura'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['carrera'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['escolaridad'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['telefono'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['correo'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['genero'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['rfc'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['curp'] ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['direccion'].",".$dato['cp'].". ".$dato['ciudad'].",".$dato['estado'].",".$dato['pais']  ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $dato['observaciones'] ?></td>
                                </tr>

                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php else: ?> 
                            <?php echo "<div class='alert alert-warning text-center'> No se encontraron Registros</div>" ?>                                   
                            <?php endif; ?>               
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

El único registro que se imprime en la tabla se imprime correctamente.
Vardump del archivo de la consulta:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(41) { ["idPersonas"]=> int(1) [0]=> int(1) ["nombre"]=> string(5) "Maria" [1]=> string(5) "Maria" ["apellidoP"]=> string(9) "Gavrilova" [2]=> string(9) "Gavrilova" ["apellidoM"]=> string(1) "X" [3]=> string(1) "X" ["foto"]=> NULL [4]=> NULL ["fechaCaptura"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" [5]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["escolaridad"]=> string(11) "Universidad" [6]=> string(11) "Universidad" ["carrera"]=> string(10) "Lic.Fisica" [7]=> string(10) "Lic.Fisica" ["telefono"]=> string(10) "6985632145" [8]=> string(10) "6985632145" ["correo"]=> string(20) "maira_gavr@gmail.com" [9]=> string(20) "maira_gavr@gmail.com" ["genero"]=> string(8) "Femenino" [10]=> string(8) "Femenino" ["rfc"]=> string(10) "EJEMPLORFC" [11]=> string(10) "EJEMPLORFC" ["curp"]=> string(11) "EJEMPLOCURP" [12]=> string(11) "EJEMPLOCURP" ["observaciones"]=> NULL [13]=> NULL ["idDireccion"]=> int(1) [14]=> int(1) [15]=> int(1) ["pais"]=> string(7) "México" [16]=> string(7) "México" ["estado"]=> string(7) "Sinaloa" [17]=> string(7) "Sinaloa" ["ciudad"]=> string(5) "Ahome" [18]=> string(5) "Ahome" ["direccion"]=> string(12) "mI DIRECCION" [19]=> string(12) "mI DIRECCION" ["cp"]=> int(85213) [20]=> int(85213) } }
```

Esto es lo que imprime el foreach de la conexión:

```
Array ( [idPersonas] => 1 [0] => 1 [nombre] => Maria [1] => Maria [apellidoP] => Gavrilova [2] => Gavrilova [apellidoM] => X [3] => X [foto] => [4] => [fechaCaptura] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [5] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [escolaridad] => Universidad [6] => Universidad [carrera] => Lic.Fisica [7] => Lic.Fisica [telefono] => 6985632145 [8] => 6985632145 [correo] => maira_gavr@gmail.com [9] => maira_gavr@gmail.com [genero] => Femenino [10] => Femenino [rfc] => EJEMPLORFC [11] => EJEMPLORFC [curp] => EJEMPLOCURP [12] => EJEMPLOCURP [observaciones] => [13] => [idDireccion] => 1 [14] => 1 ) Array ( [idPersonas] => 4 [0] => 4 [nombre] => EjemploNombre [1] => EjemploNombre [apellidoP] => EjemploApellidoP [2] => EjemploApellidoP [apellidoM] => EjemploApellidoM [3] => EjemploApellidoM [foto] => [4] => [fechaCaptura] => 2019-01-09 18:38:04 [5] => 2019-01-09 18:38:04 [escolaridad] => Universidad [6] => Universidad [carrera] => Ing.Informática [7] => Ing.Informática [telefono] => 6985632145 [8] => 6985632145 [correo] => micorreo@hotmail.com [9] => micorreo@hotmail.com [genero] => Masculino [10] => Masculino [rfc] => EJEMPLORFC [11] => EJEMPLORFC [curp] => EJEMPLOCURP [12] => EJEMPLOCURP [observaciones] => [13] => [idDireccion] => 0 [14] => 0 )
```

Comment: ¿Donde está tu apertura y cierre de `<table>` antes del `for` ... y  `</table>` después de cerrar el `for`
 ... existen realmente?

Comment: Si, ahorita modifico el código

Comment: Dado que manejas quizá cosas de alguna librería propongo que hagas una prueba simple, sin tabla, algo así: `<?php foreach ($resultado as $dato) : echo $dato['idPersonas'].PHP_EOL; endforeach; ?>` y dime si no imprime los ids uno tras otro. Así verificamos que no sea algún problema de estilo de la tabla o quién sabe qué.

Comment: Utilizo una librería para dar formato a la tabla y añadir los filtros pero no afecta a la falla, ya probé en un archivo nuevo sin la librería pero sigue arrojando un registro.

Comment: Hazlo como te digo, imprimiendo directamente, fuera de tabla y fuera de historias raras, clases css, etc, etc, etc, impresión simple, fila por fila. y fuera de todo  `div` y de cualquier contenedor. Si imprimes dentro de algo con una clase rara nadie sabe lo que te va a mostrar.

Comment: copié y pegué el código que proporcionó y me imprime1 nadamas

Comment: Muestra el resultado del `var_dump`
, (al menos parcialmente si es muy grande) puede que `fetchAll` te esté creando un array anidado y necesites dos bucles para sacar los datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88104/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-eduardo-moreno).

Comment: Una duda que me surge al ver tu consulta sql. Igualas el Persona.ID_Persona con el Direccion.ID_Direccion... p.idPersonas = d.idDireccion mi duda es, ¿No sería p.idDireccion = d.idDireccion? Es que eso te devolvería persona con id 1 y direccion con id 1, persona con id 2 y direccion con id 2 y así sucesivamente.

Comment: @Juanjo Así es,  A. Cedano me ayudó resolver el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de una laaarga discusión, el problema estaba en la consulta:

```
$sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM personas p, direccion d WHERE p.idPersonas = d.idDireccion';
```

Dado que la relación estaba mal planteada, estaba trayendo una sola fila.

Entonces, es necesario usar las columnas adecuadas en la consulta:

```
$sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM personas p, direccion d WHERE p.idDireccion = d.idDireccion';
```

A partir de ahí, los datos debería mostrarse correctamente.

Aunque yo evitaría tantas aperturas y cierras de bloques PHP, concatenando al menos dentro del for:

```
                    <tbody id="bodyTabla">
                    <?php 
                    if(!empty($resultado)):
                        $tr="";
                        foreach ($resultado as $dato):                               
                            $tr.="<tr>";
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['idPersonas']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['foto']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['nombre']." ".$dato['apellidoP']."  ".$dato['apellidoM']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['fechaCaptura']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['carrera']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['escolaridad']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['telefono']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['correo']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['genero']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['rfc']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['direccion'].", ".$dato['cp'].". ".$dato['ciudad'].",".$dato['estado'].",".$dato['pais']."</td>";                                     
                                $tr.="<td>".$dato['observaciones']."</td>";                                     
                            $tr.="</tr>";
                        endforeach;
                        echo $tr;
                    else: 
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning text-center'> No se encontraron Registros</div>";                                   
                    endif; 
                    ?>               
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: deberían ser $tr.= en vez de $tr =. Gracias por la sugerencia, desconocía esta forma de concatenar

Comment: Es cierto, error mío. Ahora edito. Prefiero esa forma que la constante mezcla de código PHP/HTML abriendo y cerrando bloques.